# Retrieving response message from WebService

Tags: java, web-services, sockets

In NetBeans I have to use the following code:

```
    public String launchRequest(String paramString)
       {
       URL localURL = new URL(paramString);
       Object localObject1 = new Socket(localURL.getHost(),  localURL.getPort());

       Object localObject2 = "GET " + paramString + " HTTP/1.0";
       localObject2 = (String)localObject2 + "\r\nAccept value: */*\r\n";
       localObject2 = (String)localObject2 + "Host value: " + localURL.getHost() + ":" + localURL.getPort() + "\r\n";
       Object localObject3 = new PrintWriter(((Socket)localObject1).getOutputStream(), true);
       ((PrintWriter)localObject3).println((String)localObject2);
       ((PrintWriter)localObject3).close();
       ((Socket)localObject1).close();

      return "OK";}
```

This code is supposed to call a webService created in C# that makes an insert operation in an Oracle Database.

 
The url that is passed looks like this:
 http://192.168.88.29:443/RaduPestrea/Services/Ort.asmx/ORTRequest?callBackDisabled=true&siren=328812656&capId=1325369

The problem is that the webService is not called. The getOutputStream() retuns an OutputStream that has no message from the WebService.
This is a part of the webService:
        `namespace Services
         {
            /// 
            /// Summary description for Service1.
            /// 
            public class Ort : System.Web.Services.WebService
            {
              [WebMethod]
              public string ORTRequest(bool callBackDisabled, int siren, int capId)
              {
                 Try{
                  .......
              return "Success ReqId :" + reqNum;
                 Catch(Exception ex)
                 {
                     return ex.ToString();
                 }
            }
          }`

The problem is I cannot modify this code. I hope the problem is from the URL I sent. 
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Agreed it is not the most beautiful code. The task is, the Java code needs to call the WebService from that URL link. That link is supposed to make an insert in a database. There is no new record in database. I use the return statements from the WebService to make sure it is called but nothing is returned. I may be doing it wrong, is there anyway to check that the WebService has been called successfully ?

 If I use the following code, the web service is called and a new record is inserted in the database.

```
<code>
    localURL = new URL(paramString);        
    localObject1 = "";        
    localObject2 = localURL.openStream();
    localObject3 = new InputStreamReader((InputStream)localObject2);
    BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader((Reader)localObject3);
    String str1;
    while ((str1 = localBufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
      String str2 = "";
      localObject1 = (String)localObject1 + str2;
    }
    return (String)localObject1;
</code>
```

Comment: Suggestion:  declare you local variables correctly instead of declaring everything as `Object` then casting it for every use of it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It still does not work. I know that what you suggested is best practice, but this is not my code and technically I am not allowed to edit it. I can only change the URL or the WebService. But firstly I want to see why it doesn't work. Why it doesn't even give an error message.

Comment: `getOutputStream()` returns an `OutputStream`. Not 'nothing'. Why you're declaring `localObject3` as an `Object` and then casting it is a mystery. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: In the OutputStream there should be the message "Success ReqId : 1234" that the WebService retuns, correct ? There is no message.

Comment: Edit is no improvement. `OutputStreams` don't 'have messages'. They are used to *send* messages.* Possibly your issue is that you aren't reading the response to the request, but it is impossible to say for sure until you clarify. The code you have been asked to work with is Grade A rubbish and should be thrown away for a fresh start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the webService is not called.

You haven't provided any evidence to that effect, and it is impossible to tell from the code you've posted.

> The getOutputStream() retuns an OutputStream that has no message from the WebService.

This is meaningless. `OutputStreams` don't contain messages from the peer. They are used to send messages *to* the peer. This statement and your title are completely nonsensical.

> Is there anyway to check that the WebService has been called successfully?

Yes. *Read the response,* and return *it,* instead of hardwiring `"OK"`.

And you've just posted code that does exactly that.

> Agreed it is not the most beautiful code.

It isn't even correct code. The HTTP headers are invalid, and it makes no attempt to read a response. It's just incompetent. Use the HttpURLConnection code you posted.

Comment: I can't use it...I have to use the one with sockets.

Comment: I say that the WebService is not called because no record is inserted in the database. If I use the HttpURLConnection code, data is inserted in the database. So the code from WebService is correct.

Comment: *"I can't use it...I have to use the one with sockets."* - Why?  Is this some homework or something?  Anyhow, if you absolutely have to use that broken code, then you will need to READ the HTTP 1.1 spec and then fix your code so that it conforms to what the spec says.  (Google "http specification" ... and start reading.)

Comment: @PestreaRadu-Constantin You *can't* use that broken code. It doesn't work. It will *never* work without being expanded by hundreds of lines to implement RFC 2616 (the HTTP 1.1 spec) correctly. You don't have a choice about this. `HttpURLConnection` already does this.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I am using vbscript. The java code is from an OLD component  created by a 3rd party that I am not allowed to touch. I have marked this as answered and I am sorry I can not mark both answers as useful because I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: So your employer or client doesn't want a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is a bad idea to use a `Socket` to make HTTP requests.  It is better to use an existing library class / method; for example:

```
new URL("https://example.com/foo/bar?param=xxx").openConnection();
```

This gives you some subclass of `URLConnnection` that you can use to form the request and get the reply from the server

There are alternative libraries for making HTTP / HTTPS requests. For example, the Apache HttpComponents libraries can be a good choice, if your requirements are complicated.

However, I suspect that the real reason that you are getting nothing back from your request, is that you are trying to talk to an "https" server (port 443) without using an SSL / TLS connection.  That ain't going to work.  The server is likely to just close the socket.

While it is possible to establish an SSL / TLS connection over a plain `Socket` (in theory) or use an `SSLSocket`, it is simpler to use a properly formed "https://..." URL and (for example) `URL.openConnection()` as above.

Moving past that, the header lines in your supposed request look syntactically invalid.  Both

```
    Accept value: ...
```

and

```
    Host value: ....
```

are wrong.  If really want to implement the HTTP message handling yourself, you need to read the HTTP 1.1 specification, and implement it to the letter.

And finally (as @EJP points out) your code isn't even reading the response.  Writing to an `OutputStream` is not going to "return" anything.  You need to read the response from an `InputStream` ... even if only to check that the request was accepted.

Comment: I have tried using the default port of 80 with no success.

Comment: Then try using `URL` and `URLConnection` as I suggested.

Comment: @PestreaRadu-Constantin 'No success' isn't a problem description, and neither is anything else you've posted here.  You won't get anything back if you aren't *reading* anything. You seem to think it should magically be 'in the `OutputStream`', which doesn't begin to make sense. It doesn't appear that anybody connected with this task has the faintest idea how to execute it. I can only suggest you do some reading, and then educate whoever wrote the original code.